# How to get comparable and reproducible results from LogisticRegressionCV and GridSearchCV

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression, logistic-regression

I want to score different classifiers with different parameters.

For speedup on `LogisticRegression` I use `LogisticRegressionCV` (which at least 2x faster) and plan use `GridSearchCV` for others.

But problem while it give me equal `C` parameters, but not the `AUC ROC` scoring.

I'll try fix many parameters like `scorer`, `random_state`, `solver`, `max_iter`, `tol`...
Please look at example (real data have no mater):

Test data and common part:

```
from sklearn import datasets
boston = datasets.load_boston()
X = boston.data
y = boston.target
y[y <= y.mean()] = 0; y[y > 0] = 1

import numpy as np
from sklearn.cross_validation import KFold
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.grid_search import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegressionCV

fold = KFold(len(y), n_folds=5, shuffle=True, random_state=777)
```

### GridSearchCV

```
grid = {
    'C': np.power(10.0, np.arange(-10, 10))
     , 'solver': ['newton-cg']
}
clf = LogisticRegression(penalty='l2', random_state=777, max_iter=10000, tol=10)
gs = GridSearchCV(clf, grid, scoring='roc_auc', cv=fold)
gs.fit(X, y)

print ('gs.best_score_:', gs.best_score_)
```

> gs.best_score_: 0.939162082194

### LogisticRegressionCV

```
searchCV = LogisticRegressionCV(
    Cs=list(np.power(10.0, np.arange(-10, 10)))
    ,penalty='l2'
    ,scoring='roc_auc'
    ,cv=fold
    ,random_state=777
    ,max_iter=10000
    ,fit_intercept=True
    ,solver='newton-cg'
    ,tol=10
)
searchCV.fit(X, y)

print ('Max auc_roc:', searchCV.scores_[1].max())
```

> Max auc_roc: 0.970588235294

Solver `newton-cg` used just to provide fixed value, other tried too.
What I forgot?

P.S. In both cases I also got warning "*/usr/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/sklearn/utils/optimize.py:193: UserWarning: Line Search failed
warnings.warn('Line Search failed')*" which I can't understand too. I'll be happy if someone also describe what it mean, but I hope it is not relevant to my main question.

#### EDIT UPDATES

By @joeln comment add `max_iter=10000` and `tol=10` parameters too. It does not change result in any digit, but the warning disappeared.

Comment: Just to be sure, could you reduce `tol` and provide that same large `max_iter` to `LogisticRegression`? If these are solving the same equation and arriving at a different minimum, it may be because it's stopping the search too early.

Comment: Thanks. I add max_iter=10000 and tol=10 (unsure what it mean) and correct question. It does not change result in any digit.

Comment: Curious. I suggested reducing, not increasing `tol`, whose default is 1e-4. In searching (as in Newton's method) around the minimum of the objective function, `tol` defines what small change is close enough to zero to say the minimum has been found. A smaller `tol` ensures optimisations with different initialisations more likely agree.

I'm not certain, but I think you should raise this as an issue on the scikit-learn tracker. `LogisticRegressionCV` is relatively new and there may be things to iron out or document better. You may need to provide some data for which this effect occurs.

Comment: Sorry for the `tol` value. What value are you suggesting? Unfortunately I newbee in ML and also uncertain... What concerned data - my example in question especially based on embedded in sklearn Boston houses demo values and fully reproducible! So, I expect what anyone just copy, paste and run it should receive exact same results.

Comment: And on all `tol` less than 10**-3 aforementioned warning appeared. On tol=(10**-7) auc_roc still 0.939162082194 and 0.970588235294 respectively.

Comment: It's good to hear this is on a shared dataset. Please raise this issue in the scikit-learn issue tracker.

Comment: I had submit issue: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/6619

Comment: Haha sorry I didn't notice how you were printing the score from `LogisticRegressionCV`. That seems to be the main source of error.

Comment: It seams so. But results still differ...

Comment: No, the difference is within `tol`

Comment: @joeln if your wish post answer with that finding summarizing bug and comment answers - I'll accept it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is a copy of the [answer by Tom](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/6619#issuecomment-205222633) on the scikit-learn issue tracker:

`LogisticRegressionCV.scores_` gives the score for all the folds.
`GridSearchCV.best_score_` gives the best mean score over all the folds.

To get the same result, you need to change your code:

```
print('Max auc_roc:', searchCV.scores_[1].max())  # is wrong
print('Max auc_roc:', searchCV.scores_[1].mean(axis=0).max())  # is correct
```

By also using the default `tol=1e-4` instead of your `tol=10`, I get:

```
('gs.best_score_:', 0.939162082193857)
('Max auc_roc:', 0.93915947999923843)
```

The (small) remaining difference might come from warm starting in `LogisticRegressionCV` (which is actually what makes it faster than `GridSearchCV`).