# Python: I want to perform 5 fold cross validation for logistic regression and report scores. Do I use LogisticRegressionCV() or cross_val_score()?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-science

cross_val_scores gives different results than LogisticRegressionCV, and I can't figure out why.

Here is my code:

```
seed = 42
test_size = .33
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(scale(X),Y, test_size=test_size, random_state=seed)

#Below is my model that I use throughout the program.

model = LogisticRegressionCV(random_state=42)
print('Logistic Regression results:')
        
#For cross_val_score below, I just call LogisticRegression (and not LogRegCV) with the same parameters.

scores = cross_val_score(LogisticRegression(random_state=42), X_train, Y_train, scoring='accuracy', cv=5)
print(np.amax(scores)*100)
print("%.2f%% average accuracy with a standard deviation of %0.2f" % (scores.mean() * 100, scores.std() * 100))
        
model.fit(X_train, Y_train)
y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
predictions = [round(value) for value in y_pred]
accuracy = accuracy_score(Y_test, predictions)

coef=np.round(model.coef_,2)

print("Accuracy: %.2f%%" % (accuracy * 100.0))
```

The output is this.

```
Logistic Regression results:
79.90483019359885
79.69% average accuracy with a standard deviation of 0.14
Accuracy: 79.81%
```

Why is the maximum accuracy from cross_val_score higher than the accuracy used by LogisticRegressionCV?

And, I recognize that cross_val_scores does not return a model, which is why I want to use LogisticRegressionCV, but I am struggling to understand why it is not performing as well. Likewise, I am not sure how to get the standard deviations of the predictors from LogisticRegressionCV.

Answer (score 1):

For me, there might be some points to take into consideration:

1. Cross validation is generally used whenever you should simulate a validation set (for instance when the training set is not that big to be divided into training, validation and test sets) and **only** uses training data. In your case you're computing accuracy of `model` on test data, making it impossible to exactly compare results.
2. According to the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/glossary.html#term-cross-validation-estimator):

> Cross-validation estimators are named EstimatorCV and tend to be roughly equivalent to GridSearchCV(Estimator(), ...). The advantage of using a cross-validation estimator over the canonical estimator class along with grid search is that they can take advantage of warm-starting by reusing precomputed results in the previous steps of the cross-validation process. This generally leads to speed improvements.

If you look at this snippet, you'll see that's what happens indeed:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.datasets import load_breast_cancer
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression, LogisticRegressionCV
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score, GridSearchCV, train_test_split

data = load_breast_cancer()
X, y = data['data'], data['target']

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)

estimator = LogisticRegression(random_state=42, solver='liblinear')
grid = {
    'C': np.power(10.0, np.arange(-10, 10)), 
}

gs = GridSearchCV(estimator, param_grid=grid, scoring='accuracy', cv=5)
gs.fit(X_train, y_train)
print(gs.best_score_)                        # 0.953846153846154

lrcv = LogisticRegressionCV(Cs=list(np.power(10.0, np.arange(-10, 10))),
                        cv=5, scoring='accuracy', solver='liblinear', random_state=42)
lrcv.fit(X_train, y_train)
print(lrcv.scores_[1].mean(axis=0).max())    # 0.953846153846154
```

I would suggest to have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36271166/how-to-get-comparable-and-reproducible-results-from-logisticregressioncv-and-gri?noredirect=1#comment60268059_36271166), too, so as to get the details of `lrcv.scores_[1].mean(axis=0).max()`.

3. Eventually, to get the same results with `cross_val_score` you should better write:

   ```
    score = cross_val_score(gs.best_estimator_, X_train, y_train, cv=5, scoring='accuracy')
    score.mean()                             # 0.953846153846154
   ```